# Small Oscillations aproximation for gravitational potential in cartesian coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, potential, harmonic-oscillator

Hi I have a question concerning the following problem, where masses 1 and 2 slide frictionless on the x axis, while mass 3 hangs from two springs connected with the other two (only the horizontal spring has natural length). I used cartesian generalized coordinates ($x_1,x_2,x_3,y_3$) for the 3 masses and I have found the equilibrium positions, and expressed the potential in a quadratic form for the spring part. For the gravitational potential I have simply $-Mgy_3$. My question is how would I approximate this part in a quadratic form? I know that for pendulums you can approximate for the angle it makes with the vertical, but here $y$ is already in a polynomial of order 1. Any hint would be appreciated.

[image]